# In python process, a C language function invoke python script method but cause segment error

Tags: c, python-3.x

today I encounter a problem which is too difficult to me. In my project, python will load a C library and invoke a init function provided by C library, and in some case of python run, a function in C library will invoke a python script function to signal the python code that data comes and check it. I have write a demo to simulate the case, but then error occurs, below is my code:
**C Library Code:**

```
#include <test.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include <string.h>

void sig_handler(int sig) {
  PyObject *p_name = NULL;
  PyObject *p_func = NULL;
  PyObject *p_args = NULL;
  PyObject *p_value = NULL;
  PyObject *p_module = NULL;

  char *module_name = "pyfunction";
  char *function_name = "c_py_function";

  Py_Initialize();
  PyGILState_STATE d_gstate;
  d_gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

  p_name = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(module_name);
  Py_DECREF(p_name);

  p_module = PyImport_Import(p_name);
  if (p_module != NULL) {
    p_func = PyObject_GetAttrString(p_module, function_name);
    if (p_func && PyCallable_Check(p_func)) {
      p_value = PyObject_CallObject(p_func, p_args);
      if (p_value != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Result of call function %s is %ld\n", 
                function_name, PyLong_AsLong(p_value));
        Py_DECREF(p_value);
        Py_Finalize();
      }
    } else {
      Py_DECREF(p_func);
      Py_DECREF(p_module);

      if (PyErr_Occurred())
        PyErr_Print();
      Py_Finalize();

      fprintf(stderr, "Call %s failed\n", function_name);
      abort();
    }
  } else {
    PyErr_Print();
    Py_Finalize();

    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load python module %s\n", module_name);
    abort();
  }
}

int Init_c_base(void) {
  int ret = 0;
  struct sigaction new;
  struct sigaction old;

  sigemptyset(&new.sa_mask);
  sigemptyset(&new.sa_mask);

  new.sa_flags = 0;
  new.sa_handler = sig_handler;

  ret = sigaction(SIGUSR1, &new, &old);
  if (ret != 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "Finish init c environment base.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

**Python Script code:**

```
import time
import threading
import concurrent.futures
import run

g_stop_run = 0

def thread_fn_1():
    global g_stop_run

    while not g_stop_run:
        print("Thread %u is runing" % threading.get_ident())
        time.sleep(1)
    return 1

def thread_fn_2():
    global g_stop_run

    while not g_stop_run:
        print("Thread %u is runing" % threading.get_ident())
        time.sleep(1)
    return 2

def c_py_function():
    global g_stop_run

    print("Thread %u run, send exit signal." % threading.get_ident())
    g_stop_run = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run.Init_c_base()
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)

    futures = []
    futures.append(executor.submit(thread_fn_1))
    futures.append(executor.submit(thread_fn_2))

    time.sleep(100)
    print("Thread execute result is:\n")
    for f in futures:
        print(f.result())

    print("Main thread is %u" % threading.get_ident())
```

**SWIG FILE:**

```
// run.i - Swig interface.
%module run
%{
#include "test.h"
%}

extern int Init_c_base(void);
```

The C library code will compile to `.so` and enable python invoke via `SWIG`, and in my demo python first call `Init_c_base` in C library and the `Init_c_base` will registe a signal handler `sig_handler` of `SIGUSR1`. Then send `SIGUSR1` to python, the `sig_handler` run at once, but cause a segment fault.

bt of segment fault is:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f2b4667064a in convertsimple (arg=0x7f2b3f262cf0, p_format=p_format@entry=0x7fffe09b7b58, p_va=<optimized out>, flags=0, msgbuf=0x7fffe09b7d30 "p}\233\340\377\177", bufsize=bufsize@entry=512, 
    freelist=freelist@entry=0x7fffe09b7c20) at Python/getargs.c:1216
#1  0x00007f2b46670a49 in convertitem (arg=arg@entry=0x7f2b3f262cf0, p_format=p_format@entry=0x7fffe09b7bf8, p_va=p_va@entry=0x7fffe09b7f78, flags=flags@entry=0, levels=levels@entry=0x7fffe09b7cb0, 
    msgbuf=msgbuf@entry=0x7fffe09b7d30 "p}\233\340\377\177", bufsize=bufsize@entry=512, freelist=freelist@entry=0x7fffe09b7c20) at Python/getargs.c:549
#2  0x00007f2b466718b2 in vgetargskeywords (args=0x7f2b3b0c8410, keywords=0x0, format=0x7f2b467454bb "U|OOOi:__import__", kwlist=0x7f2b469e7ce0 <kwlist.12206>, p_va=p_va@entry=0x7fffe09b7f78, 
    flags=flags@entry=0) at Python/getargs.c:1739
#3  0x00007f2b46672cb6 in PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords (args=<optimized out>, keywords=<optimized out>, format=format@entry=0x7f2b467454bb "U|OOOi:__import__", kwlist=kwlist@entry=0x7f2b469e7ce0 <kwlist.12206>)
    at Python/getargs.c:1363
#4  0x00007f2b46648090 in builtin___import__ (self=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, kwds=<optimized out>) at Python/bltinmodule.c:235
#5  0x00007f2b465a3822 in PyCFunction_Call (func=0x7f2b46bef508, args=0x7f2b3b0c8410, kwds=0x0) at Objects/methodobject.c:98
#6  0x00007f2b46544463 in PyObject_Call (func=0x7f2b46bef508, args=0x7f2b3b0c8410, kwargs=kwargs@entry=0x0) at Objects/abstract.c:2261
#7  0x00007f2b465447c6 in call_function_tail (callable=callable@entry=0x7f2b46bef508, args=args@entry=0x7f2b3b0c8410) at Objects/abstract.c:2512
#8  0x00007f2b46544ec7 in PyObject_CallFunction (callable=callable@entry=0x7f2b46bef508, format=format@entry=0x7f2b4674d908 "OOOOi") at Objects/abstract.c:2539
#9  0x00007f2b466772c0 in PyImport_Import (module_name=0x7f2b3f262cf0) at Python/import.c:1767
#10 0x00007f2b3aeb7b8b in sig_handler (sig=10) at test.c:24
#11 <signal handler called>
#12 0x00007f2b458da0d3 in __select_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#13 0x00007f2b466db876 in pysleep (secs=100000000000) at ./Modules/timemodule.c:1467
#14 0x00007f2b466db929 in time_sleep (self=<optimized out>, obj=<optimized out>) at ./Modules/timemodule.c:235
#15 0x00007f2b465a35fc in _PyCFunction_FastCallDict (func_obj=func_obj@entry=0x7f2b3f26c490, args=args@entry=0x19088b8, nargs=nargs@entry=1, kwargs=kwargs@entry=0x0) at Objects/methodobject.c:209
#16 0x00007f2b465a3a67 in _PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords (func=func@entry=0x7f2b3f26c490, stack=stack@entry=0x19088b8, nargs=nargs@entry=1, kwnames=kwnames@entry=0x0) at Objects/methodobject.c:294
#17 0x00007f2b4664d287 in call_function (pp_stack=pp_stack@entry=0x7fffe09b9198, oparg=oparg@entry=1, kwnames=kwnames@entry=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:4851
#18 0x00007f2b46657382 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (f=0x1908728, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3335
#19 0x00007f2b4664c3bb in PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=f@entry=0x1908728, throwflag=throwflag@entry=0) at Python/ceval.c:754
#20 0x00007f2b4664ce5f in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName (_co=0x7f2b3f286c40, globals=<optimized out>, locals=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, argcount=argcount@entry=0, kwnames=0x0, kwargs=kwargs@entry=0x0, 
    kwcount=kwcount@entry=0, kwstep=kwstep@entry=2, defs=defs@entry=0x0, defcount=defcount@entry=0, kwdefs=kwdefs@entry=0x0, closure=closure@entry=0x0, name=name@entry=0x0, qualname=qualname@entry=0x0)
    at Python/ceval.c:4166
#21 0x00007f2b4664d4da in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (_co=_co@entry=0x7f2b3f286c40, globals=globals@entry=0x7f2b46b27c88, locals=locals@entry=0x7f2b46b27c88, args=args@entry=0x0, argcount=argcount@entry=0, 
    kws=kws@entry=0x0, kwcount=kwcount@entry=0, defs=defs@entry=0x0, defcount=defcount@entry=0, kwdefs=kwdefs@entry=0x0, closure=closure@entry=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:4187
#22 0x00007f2b4664d524 in PyEval_EvalCode (co=co@entry=0x7f2b3f286c40, globals=globals@entry=0x7f2b46b27c88, locals=locals@entry=0x7f2b46b27c88) at Python/ceval.c:731
#23 0x00007f2b46684979 in run_mod (mod=mod@entry=0x18ed3d0, filename=filename@entry=0x7f2b3f2627b0, globals=globals@entry=0x7f2b46b27c88, locals=locals@entry=0x7f2b46b27c88, flags=flags@entry=0x7fffe09b9540, 
    arena=arena@entry=0x7f2b3f264220) at Python/pythonrun.c:1025
#24 0x00007f2b46687644 in PyRun_FileExFlags (fp=fp@entry=0x1924ae0, filename_str=filename_str@entry=0x7f2b3f2641f0 "pyfunction.py", start=start@entry=257, globals=globals@entry=0x7f2b46b27c88, 
    locals=locals@entry=0x7f2b46b27c88, closeit=closeit@entry=1, flags=flags@entry=0x7fffe09b9540) at Python/pythonrun.c:978
#25 0x00007f2b46687a0e in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags (fp=fp@entry=0x1924ae0, filename=<optimized out>, filename@entry=0x7f2b3f2641f0 "pyfunction.py", closeit=closeit@entry=1, flags=flags@entry=0x7fffe09b9540)
    at Python/pythonrun.c:419
#26 0x00007f2b46687bcf in PyRun_AnyFileExFlags (fp=fp@entry=0x1924ae0, filename=0x7f2b3f2641f0 "pyfunction.py", closeit=closeit@entry=1, flags=flags@entry=0x7fffe09b9540) at Python/pythonrun.c:81
#27 0x00007f2b466a028d in run_file (fp=fp@entry=0x1924ae0, filename=filename@entry=0x18a72c0 L"pyfunction.py", p_cf=p_cf@entry=0x7fffe09b9540) at Modules/main.c:340
#28 0x00007f2b466a0f3a in Py_Main (argc=argc@entry=2, argv=argv@entry=0x18a6010) at Modules/main.c:810
#29 0x0000000000400b6d in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffe09b96b8) at ./Programs/python.c:69
```

I am very confused about this problem, and I wonder whether python support the case I encounter, and could you please tell me how to solve this problem if support?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `PyImport_Import` is not the right choice, change to `PyImport_ImportModule` take effect. So the C code can be:

```
#include <test.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include <string.h>

void sig_handler(int sig) {
  PyObject *p_name = NULL;
  PyObject *p_func = NULL;
  PyObject *p_args = NULL;
  PyObject *p_value = NULL;
  PyObject *p_module = NULL;

  char *module_name = "pyfunction";
  char *function_name = "c_py_function";

  if (!Py_IsInitialized()) {
    Py_Initialize();
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Python environment is already initialized.\n");
  }

  PyGILState_STATE d_gstate;
  d_gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

  p_module = PyImport_ImportModule(module_name);
  if (p_module != NULL) {
    p_func = PyObject_GetAttrString(p_module, function_name);
    if (p_func && PyCallable_Check(p_func)) {
      p_value = PyObject_CallObject(p_func, NULL);
      if (p_value != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Result of call function %s is %ld\n", 
                function_name, PyLong_AsLong(p_value));
        Py_DECREF(p_value);
        PyGILState_Release(d_gstate);
        Py_XDECREF(p_func);
        Py_DECREF(p_module);
      }
    } else {
      Py_DECREF(p_func);
      Py_DECREF(p_module);

      if (PyErr_Occurred())
        PyErr_Print();

      fprintf(stderr, "Call %s failed\n", function_name);
      abort();
    }
  } else {
    PyErr_Print();

    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load python module %s\n", module_name);
    abort();
  }
}

int Init_c_base(void) {
  int ret = 0;
  struct sigaction new;
  struct sigaction old;

  sigemptyset(&new.sa_mask);
  sigemptyset(&new.sa_mask);

  new.sa_flags = 0;
  new.sa_handler = sig_handler;

  ret = sigaction(SIGUSR1, &new, &old);
  if (ret != 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "Finish init c environment base.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Python version is Python 3.6.8, compile flags is:

```
{'prefix': '/home/usnic/.local', 'exec_prefix': '/home/usnic/.local', 'py_version': '3.6.8', 'py_version_short': '3.6', 'py_version_nodot': '36', 'installed_base': '/home/usnic/.local', 'base': '/home/usnic/.local', 'installed_platbase': '/home/usnic/.local', 'platbase': '/home/usnic/.local', 'projectbase': '/home/usnic/.local/bin', 'abiflags': 'dm', 'ABIFLAGS': 'dm', 'AC_APPLE_UNIVERSAL_BUILD': 0, 'AIX_GENUINE_CPLUSPLUS': 0, 'ANDROID_API_LEVEL': 0, 'AR': 'ar', 'ARFLAGS': 'rcs', 'BASECFLAGS': '-Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare', 'BASECPPFLAGS': '', 'BASEMODLIBS': '', 'BINDIR': '/home/usnic/.local/bin', 'BINLIBDEST': '/home/usnic/.local/lib/python3.6', 'BLDLIBRARY': '-L. -lpython3.6dm', 'BLDSHARED': 'gcc -pthread -shared', 'BUILDEXE': '', 'BUILDPYTHON': 'python', 'BUILD_GNU_TYPE': 'x86_64-pc-linux-gnu', 'BYTESTR_DEPS': '\\', 'CC': 'gcc -pthread', 'CCSHARED': '-fPIC', 'CFLAGS': '-Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -Og -Wall', 'CFLAGSFORSHARED': '-fPIC', 'CFLAGS_ALIASING': '', 'CFLAGS_NODIST': '', 'CONFIGFILES': 'configure configure.ac acconfig.h pyconfig.h.in Makefile.pre.in', 'CONFIGURE_CFLAGS': '', 'CONFIGURE_CFLAGS_NODIST': '-std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers', 'CONFIGURE_CPPFLAGS': '', 'CONFIGURE_LDFLAGS': '', 'CONFIGURE_LDFLAGS_NODIST': '', 'CONFIG_ARGS': "'--prefix=/home/usnic/.local/' '--enable-shared' '--with-pydebug'", 'CONFINCLUDEDIR': '/home/usnic/.local/include', 'CONFINCLUDEPY': '/home/usnic/.local/include/python3.6dm', 'COREPYTHONPATH': ':', 'COVERAGE_INFO': '/home/usnic/Python-3.6.8/coverage.info', 'COVERAGE_REPORT': '/home/usnic/Python-3.6.8/lcov-report', 'COVERAGE_REPORT_OPTIONS': '--no-branch-coverage --title "CPython lcov report"', 'CPPFLAGS': '-I. -I./Include', 'CXX': 'g++ -pthread', 'DESTDIRS': '/home/usnic/.local /home/usnic/.local/lib /home/usnic/.local/lib/python3.6 /home/usnic/.local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 'DESTLIB': '/home/usnic/.local/lib/python3.6', 'DESTPATH': '', 'DESTSHARED': '/home/usnic/.local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 'DFLAGS': '', 'DIRMODE': 755, 'DIST': 'README ChangeLog configure configure.ac acconfig.h pyconfig.h.in Makefile.pre.in Include Lib Misc Ext-dummy', 'DISTDIRS': 'Include Lib Misc Ext-dummy', 'DISTFILES': 'README ChangeLog configure configure.ac acconfig.h pyconfig.h.in Makefile.pre.in', 'DLINCLDIR': '.', 'DLLLIBRARY': '', 'DOUBLE_IS_ARM_MIXED_ENDIAN_IEEE754': 0, 'DOUBLE_IS_BIG_ENDIAN_IEEE754': 0, 'DOUBLE_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN_IEEE754': 1, 'DTRACE': '', 'DTRACE_DEPS': '\\', 'DTRACE_HEADERS': '', 'DTRACE_OBJS': '', 'DYNLOADFILE': 'dynload_shlib.o', 'ENABLE_IPV6': 1, 'ENSUREPIP': 'upgrade', 'EXE': '', 'EXEMODE': 755, 'EXTRAMACHDEPPATH': '', 'EXTRATESTOPTS': '', 'EXTRA_CFLAGS': '', 'EXT_SUFFIX': '.cpython-36dm-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', 'FILEMODE': 644, 'FLOCK_NEEDS_LIBBSD': 0, 'GETPGRP_HAVE_ARG': 0, 'GETTIMEOFDAY_NO_TZ': 0, 'GITBRANCH': '', 'GITTAG': '', 'GITVERSION': '', 'GNULD': 'yes', 'HAVE_ACCEPT4': 1, 'HAVE_ACOSH': 1, 'HAVE_ADDRINFO': 1, 'HAVE_ALARM': 1, 'HAVE_ALIGNED_REQUIRED': 0, 'HAVE_ALLOCA_H': 1, 'HAVE_ALTZONE': 0, 'HAVE_ASINH': 1, 'HAVE_ASM_TYPES_H': 1, 'HAVE_ATANH': 1, 'HAVE_BIND_TEXTDOMAIN_CODESET': 1, 'HAVE_BLUETOOTH_BLUETOOTH_H': 0, 'HAVE_BLUETOOTH_H': 0, 'HAVE_BROKEN_MBSTOWCS': 0, 'HAVE_BROKEN_NICE': 0, 'HAVE_BROKEN_PIPE_BUF': 0, 'HAVE_BROKEN_POLL': 0, 'HAVE_BROKEN_POSIX_SEMAPHORES': 0, 'HAVE_BROKEN_PTHREAD_SIGMASK': 0, 'HAVE_BROKEN_SEM_GETVALUE': 0, 'HAVE_BROKEN_UNSETENV': 0, 'HAVE_BUILTIN_ATOMIC': 1, 'HAVE_CHFLAGS': 0, 'HAVE_CHOWN': 1, 'HAVE_CHROOT': 1, 'HAVE_CLOCK': 1, 'HAVE_CLOCK_GETRES': 1, 'HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME': 1, 'HAVE_CLOCK_SETTIME': 1, 'HAVE_COMPUTED_GOTOS': 1, 'HAVE_CONFSTR': 1, 'HAVE_CONIO_H': 0, 'HAVE_COPYSIGN': 1, 'HAVE_CRYPT_H': 1, 'HAVE_CTERMID': 1, 'HAVE_CTERMID_R': 0, 'HAVE_CURSES_FILTER': 1, 'HAVE_CURSES_H': 1, 'HAVE_CURSES_HAS_KEY': 1, 'HAVE_CURSES_IMMEDOK': 1, 'HAVE_CURSES_IS_PAD': 1, 'HAVE_CURSES_IS_TERM_RESIZED': 1, 'HAVE_CURSES_RESIZETERM': 1, 'HAVE_CURSES_RESIZE_TERM': 1, 'HAVE_CURSES_SYNCOK': 1, 'HAVE_CURSES_TYPEAHEAD': 1, 'HAVE_CURSES_USE_ENV': 1, 'HAVE_CURSES_WCHGAT': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_ISFINITE': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_ISINF': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_ISNAN': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_RTLD_DEEPBIND': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_RTLD_GLOBAL': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_RTLD_LAZY': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_RTLD_LOCAL': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_RTLD_NODELETE': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_RTLD_NOLOAD': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_RTLD_NOW': 1, 'HAVE_DECL_TZNAME': 0, 'HAVE_DEVICE_MACROS': 1, 'HAVE_DEV_PTC': 0, 'HAVE_DEV_PTMX': 1, 'HAVE_DIRECT_H': 0, 'HAVE_DIRENT_D_TYPE': 1, 'HAVE_DIRENT_H': 1, 'HAVE_DIRFD': 1, 'HAVE_DLFCN_H': 1, 'HAVE_DLOPEN': 1, 'HAVE_DUP2': 1, 'HAVE_DUP3': 1, 'HAVE_DYNAMIC_LOADING': 1, 'HAVE_ENDIAN_H': 1, 'HAVE_EPOLL': 1, 'HAVE_EPOLL_CREATE1': 1, 'HAVE_ERF': 1, 'HAVE_ERFC': 1, 'HAVE_ERRNO_H': 1, 'HAVE_EXECV': 1, 'HAVE_EXPM1': 1, 'HAVE_FACCESSAT': 1, 'HAVE_FCHDIR': 1, 'HAVE_FCHMOD': 1, 'HAVE_FCHMODAT': 1, 'HAVE_FCHOWN': 1, 'HAVE_FCHOWNAT': 1, 'HAVE_FCNTL_H': 1, 'HAVE_FDATASYNC': 1, 'HAVE_FDOPENDIR': 1, 'HAVE_FEXECVE': 1, 'HAVE_FINITE': 1, 'HAVE_FLOCK': 1, 'HAVE_FORK': 1, 'HAVE_FORKPTY': 1, 'HAVE_FPATHCONF': 1, 'HAVE_FSEEK64': 0, 'HAVE_FSEEKO': 1, 'HAVE_FSTATAT': 1, 'HAVE_FSTATVFS': 1, 'HAVE_FSYNC': 1, 'HAVE_FTELL64': 0, 'HAVE_FTELLO': 1, 'HAVE_FTIME': 1, 'HAVE_FTRUNCATE': 1, 'HAVE_FUTIMENS': 1, 'HAVE_FUTIMES': 1, 'HAVE_FUTIMESAT': 1, 'HAVE_GAI_STRERROR': 1, 'HAVE_GAMMA': 1, 'HAVE_GCC_ASM_FOR_MC68881': 0, 'HAVE_GCC_ASM_FOR_X64': 1, 'HAVE_GCC_ASM_FOR_X87': 1, 'HAVE_GCC_UINT128_T': 1, 'HAVE_GETADDRINFO': 1, 'HAVE_GETC_UNLOCKED': 1, 'HAVE_GETENTROPY': 0, 'HAVE_GETGROUPLIST': 1, 'HAVE_GETGROUPS': 1, 'HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME': 0, 'HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R': 1, 'HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_3_ARG': 0, 'HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_5_ARG': 0, 'HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_6_ARG': 1, 'HAVE_GETITIMER': 1, 'HAVE_GETLOADAVG': 1, 'HAVE_GETLOGIN': 1, 'HAVE_GETNAMEINFO': 1, 'HAVE_GETPAGESIZE': 1, 'HAVE_GETPEERNAME': 1, 'HAVE_GETPGID': 1, 'HAVE_GETPGRP': 1, 'HAVE_GETPID': 1, 'HAVE_GETPRIORITY': 1, 'HAVE_GETPWENT': 1, 'HAVE_GETRANDOM': 0, 'HAVE_GETRANDOM_SYSCALL': 1, 'HAVE_GETRESGID': 1, 'HAVE_GETRESUID': 1, 'HAVE_GETSID': 1, 'HAVE_GETSPENT': 1, 'HAVE_GETSPNAM': 1, 'HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY': 1, 'HAVE_GETWD': 1, 'HAVE_GLIBC_MEMMOVE_BUG': 0, 'HAVE_GRP_H': 1, 'HAVE_HSTRERROR': 1, 'HAVE_HTOLE64': 1, 'HAVE_HYPOT': 1, 'HAVE_IEEEFP_H': 0, 'HAVE_IF_NAMEINDEX': 1, 'HAVE_INET_ATON': 1, 'HAVE_INET_PTON': 1, 'HAVE_INITGROUPS': 1, 'HAVE_INTTYPES_H': 1, 'HAVE_IO_H': 0, 'HAVE_IPA_PURE_CONST_BUG': 0, 'HAVE_KILL': 1, 'HAVE_KILLPG': 1, 'HAVE_KQUEUE': 0, 'HAVE_LANGINFO_H': 1, 'HAVE_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT': 0, 'HAVE_LCHFLAGS': 0, 'HAVE_LCHMOD': 0, 'HAVE_LCHOWN': 1, 'HAVE_LGAMMA': 1, 'HAVE_LIBDL': 1, 'HAVE_LIBDLD': 0, 'HAVE_LIBIEEE': 0, 'HAVE_LIBINTL_H': 1, 'HAVE_LIBREADLINE': 0, 'HAVE_LIBRESOLV': 0, 'HAVE_LIBSENDFILE': 0, 'HAVE_LIBUTIL_H': 0, 'HAVE_LINK': 1, 'HAVE_LINKAT': 1, 'HAVE_LINUX_CAN_BCM_H': 1, 'HAVE_LINUX_CAN_H': 1, 'HAVE_LINUX_CAN_RAW_FD_FRAMES': 1, 'HAVE_LINUX_CAN_RAW_H': 1, 'HAVE_LINUX_NETLINK_H': 1, 'HAVE_LINUX_RANDOM_H': 1, 'HAVE_LINUX_TIPC_H': 1, 'HAVE_LOCKF': 1, 'HAVE_LOG1P': 1, 'HAVE_LOG2': 1, 'HAVE_LONG_DOUBLE': 1, 'HAVE_LSTAT': 1, 'HAVE_LUTIMES': 1, 'HAVE_MAKEDEV': 1, 'HAVE_MBRTOWC': 1, 'HAVE_MEMMOVE': 1, 'HAVE_MEMORY_H': 1, 'HAVE_MEMRCHR': 1, 'HAVE_MKDIRAT': 1, 'HAVE_MKFIFO': 1, 'HAVE_MKFIFOAT': 1, 'HAVE_MKNOD': 1, 'HAVE_MKNODAT': 1, 'HAVE_MKTIME': 1, 'HAVE_MMAP': 1, 'HAVE_MREMAP': 1, 'HAVE_NCURSES_H': 1, 'HAVE_NDIR_H': 0, 'HAVE_NETPACKET_PACKET_H': 1, 'HAVE_NET_IF_H': 1, 'HAVE_NICE': 1, 'HAVE_OPENAT': 1, 'HAVE_OPENPTY': 1, 'HAVE_PATHCONF': 1, 'HAVE_PAUSE': 1, 'HAVE_PIPE2': 1, 'HAVE_PLOCK': 0, 'HAVE_POLL': 1, 'HAVE_POLL_H': 1, 'HAVE_POSIX_FADVISE': 1, 'HAVE_POSIX_FALLOCATE': 1, 'HAVE_PREAD': 1, 'HAVE_PRLIMIT': 1, 'HAVE_PROCESS_H': 0, 'HAVE_PROTOTYPES': 1, 'HAVE_PTHREAD_ATFORK': 1, 'HAVE_PTHREAD_DESTRUCTOR': 0, 'HAVE_PTHREAD_H': 1, 'HAVE_PTHREAD_INIT': 0, 'HAVE_PTHREAD_KILL': 1, 'HAVE_PTHREAD_SIGMASK': 1, 'HAVE_PTY_H': 1, 'HAVE_PUTENV': 1, 'HAVE_PWRITE': 1, 'HAVE_READLINK': 1, 'HAVE_READLINKAT': 1, 'HAVE_READV': 1, 'HAVE_REALPATH': 1, 'HAVE_RENAMEAT': 1, 'HAVE_RL_APPEND_HISTORY': 0, 'HAVE_RL_CALLBACK': 0, 'HAVE_RL_CATCH_SIGNAL': 0, 'HAVE_RL_COMPLETION_APPEND_CHARACTER': 0, 'HAVE_RL_COMPLETION_DISPLAY_MATCHES_HOOK': 0, 'HAVE_RL_COMPLETION_MATCHES': 0, 'HAVE_RL_COMPLETION_SUPPRESS_APPEND': 0, 'HAVE_RL_PRE_INPUT_HOOK': 0, 'HAVE_RL_RESIZE_TERMINAL': 0, 'HAVE_ROUND': 1, 'HAVE_SCHED_GET_PRIORITY_MAX': 1, 'HAVE_SCHED_H': 1, 'HAVE_SCHED_RR_GET_INTERVAL': 1, 'HAVE_SCHED_SETAFFINITY': 1, 'HAVE_SCHED_SETPARAM': 1, 'HAVE_SCHED_SETSCHEDULER': 1, 'HAVE_SELECT': 1, 'HAVE_SEM_GETVALUE': 1, 'HAVE_SEM_OPEN': 1, 'HAVE_SEM_TIMEDWAIT': 1, 'HAVE_SEM_UNLINK': 1, 'HAVE_SENDFILE': 1, 'HAVE_SETEGID': 1, 'HAVE_SETEUID': 1, 'HAVE_SETGID': 1, 'HAVE_SETGROUPS': 1, 'HAVE_SETHOSTNAME': 1, 'HAVE_SETITIMER': 1, 'HAVE_SETLOCALE': 1, 'HAVE_SETPGID': 1, 'HAVE_SETPGRP': 1, 'HAVE_SETPRIORITY': 1, 'HAVE_SETREGID': 1, 'HAVE_SETRESGID': 1, 'HAVE_SETRESUID': 1, 'HAVE_SETREUID': 1, 'HAVE_SETSID': 1, 'HAVE_SETUID': 1, 'HAVE_SETVBUF': 1, 'HAVE_SHADOW_H': 1, 'HAVE_SIGACTION': 1, 'HAVE_SIGALTSTACK': 1, 'HAVE_SIGINTERRUPT': 1, 'HAVE_SIGNAL_H': 1, 'HAVE_SIGPENDING': 1, 'HAVE_SIGRELSE': 1, 'HAVE_SIGTIMEDWAIT': 1, 'HAVE_SIGWAIT': 1, 'HAVE_SIGWAITINFO': 1, 'HAVE_SNPRINTF': 1, 'HAVE_SOCKADDR_ALG': 1, 'HAVE_SOCKADDR_SA_LEN': 0, 'HAVE_SOCKADDR_STORAGE': 1, 'HAVE_SOCKETPAIR': 1, 'HAVE_SPAWN_H': 1, 'HAVE_SSIZE_T': 1, 'HAVE_STATVFS': 1, 'HAVE_STAT_TV_NSEC': 1, 'HAVE_STAT_TV_NSEC2': 0, 'HAVE_STDARG_PROTOTYPES': 1, 'HAVE_STDINT_H': 1, 'HAVE_STDLIB_H': 1, 'HAVE_STD_ATOMIC': 0, 'HAVE_STRDUP': 1, 'HAVE_STRFTIME': 1, 'HAVE_STRINGS_H': 1, 'HAVE_STRING_H': 1, 'HAVE_STRLCPY': 0, 'HAVE_STROPTS_H': 0, 'HAVE_STRUCT_PASSWD_PW_GECOS': 1, 'HAVE_STRUCT_PASSWD_PW_PASSWD': 1, 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_BIRTHTIME': 0, 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_BLKSIZE': 1, 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_BLOCKS': 1, 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_FLAGS': 0, 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_GEN': 0, 'HAVE_STRUCT_STAT_ST_RDEV': 1, 'HAVE_STRUCT_TM_TM_ZONE': 1, 'HAVE_SYMLINK': 1, 'HAVE_SYMLINKAT': 1, 'HAVE_SYNC': 1, 'HAVE_SYSCONF': 1, 'HAVE_SYSEXITS_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_AUDIOIO_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_BSDTTY_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_DEVPOLL_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_DIR_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_ENDIAN_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_EPOLL_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_EVENT_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_FILE_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_IOCTL_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_KERN_CONTROL_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_LOADAVG_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_LOCK_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_MKDEV_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_MODEM_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_NDIR_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_PARAM_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_POLL_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_RANDOM_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_RESOURCE_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_SELECT_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_SENDFILE_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_STATVFS_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_STAT_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_SYSCALL_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_SYSMACROS_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_SYS_DOMAIN_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_TERMIO_H': 0, 'HAVE_SYS_TIMES_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_TIME_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_UIO_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_UN_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_UTSNAME_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_WAIT_H': 1, 'HAVE_SYS_XATTR_H': 1, 'HAVE_TCGETPGRP': 1, 'HAVE_TCSETPGRP': 1, 'HAVE_TEMPNAM': 1, 'HAVE_TERMIOS_H': 1, 'HAVE_TERM_H': 1, 'HAVE_TGAMMA': 1, 'HAVE_TIMEGM': 1, 'HAVE_TIMES': 1, 'HAVE_TMPFILE': 1, 'HAVE_TMPNAM': 1, 'HAVE_TMPNAM_R': 1, 'HAVE_TM_ZONE': 1, 'HAVE_TRUNCATE': 1, 'HAVE_TZNAME': 0, 'HAVE_UCS4_TCL': 0, 'HAVE_UNAME': 1, 'HAVE_UNISTD_H': 1, 'HAVE_UNLINKAT': 1, 'HAVE_UNSETENV': 1, 'HAVE_USABLE_WCHAR_T': 0, 'HAVE_UTIL_H': 0, 'HAVE_UTIMENSAT': 1, 'HAVE_UTIMES': 1, 'HAVE_UTIME_H': 1, 'HAVE_WAIT3': 1, 'HAVE_WAIT4': 1, 'HAVE_WAITID': 1, 'HAVE_WAITPID': 1, 'HAVE_WCHAR_H': 1, 'HAVE_WCSCOLL': 1, 'HAVE_WCSFTIME': 1, 'HAVE_WCSXFRM': 1, 'HAVE_WMEMCMP': 1, 'HAVE_WORKING_TZSET': 1, 'HAVE_WRITEV': 1, 'HAVE_ZLIB_COPY': 1, 'HAVE__GETPTY': 0, 'HOST_GNU_TYPE': 'x86_64-pc-linux-gnu', 'INCLDIRSTOMAKE': '/home/usnic/.local/include /home/usnic/.local/include /home/usnic/.local/include/python3.6dm /home/usnic/.local/include/python3.6dm', 'INCLUDEDIR': '/home/usnic/.local/include', 'INCLUDEPY': '/home/usnic/.local/include/python3.6dm', 'INSTALL': '/usr/bin/install -c', 'INSTALL_DATA': '/usr/bin/install -c -m 644', 'INSTALL_PROGRAM': '/usr/bin/install -c', 'INSTALL_SCRIPT': '/usr/bin/install -c', 'INSTALL_SHARED': '/usr/bin/install -c -m 555', 'INSTSONAME': 'libpython3.6dm.so.1.0', 'IO_H': 'Modules/_io/_iomodule.h', 'IO_OBJS': '\\', 'LDCXXSHARED': 'g++ -pthread -shared', 'LDFLAGS': '', 'LDFLAGS_NODIST': '', 'LDLAST': '', 'LDLIBRARY': 'libpython3.6dm.so', 'LDLIBRARYDIR': '', 'LDSHARED': 'gcc -pthread -shared', 'LDVERSION': '3.6dm', 'LIBC': '', 'LIBDEST': '/home/usnic/.local/lib/python3.6', 'LIBDIR': '/home/usnic/.local/lib', 'LIBFFI_INCLUDEDIR': '', 'LIBM': '-lm', 'LIBOBJDIR': 'Python/', 'LIBOBJS': '', 'LIBPC': '/home/usnic/.local/lib/pkgconfig', 'LIBPL': '/home/usnic/.local/lib/python3.6/config-3.6dm-x86_64-linux-gnu', 'LIBRARY': 'libpython3.6dm.a', 'LIBRARY_OBJS': '\\', 'LIBRARY_OBJS_OMIT_FROZEN': '\\', 'LIBS': '-lpthread -ldl  -lutil', 'LIBSUBDIRS': 'tkinter tkinter/test tkinter/test/test_tkinter \\', 'LINKCC': 'gcc -pthread', 'LINKFORSHARED': '-Xlinker -export-dynamic', 'LIPO_32BIT_FLAGS': '', 'LLVM_PROF_ERR': 'no', 'LLVM_PROF_FILE': '', 'LLVM_PROF_MERGER': 'true', 'LN': 'ln', 'LOCALMODLIBS': '', 'LOG1P_DROPS_ZERO_SIGN': 0, 'MACHDEP': 'linux', 'MACHDEPPATH': ':', 'MACHDEP_OBJS': '', 'MACHDESTLIB': '/home/usnic/.local/lib/python3.6', 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET': '', 'MAINCC': 'gcc -pthread', 'MAJOR_IN_MKDEV': 0, 'MAJOR_IN_SYSMACROS': 0, 'MAKESETUP': './Modules/makesetup', 'MANDIR': '/home/usnic/.local/share/man', 'MKDIR_P': '/usr/bin/mkdir -p', 'MODLIBS': '', 'MODNAMES': '_thread posix errno pwd _sre _codecs _weakref _functools _operator _collections itertools atexit _signal _stat time _locale _io zipimport faulthandler _tracemalloc _symtable xxsubtype', 'MODOBJS': 'Modules/_threadmodule.o  Modules/posixmodule.o  Modules/errnomodule.o  Modules/pwdmodule.o  Modules/_sre.o  Modules/_codecsmodule.o  Modules/_weakref.o  Modules/_functoolsmodule.o  Modules/_operator.o  Modules/_collectionsmodule.o  Modules/itertoolsmodule.o  Modules/atexitmodule.o  Modules/signalmodule.o  Modules/_stat.o  Modules/timemodule.o  Modules/_localemodule.o  Modules/_iomodule.o Modules/iobase.o Modules/fileio.o Modules/bytesio.o Modules/bufferedio.o Modules/textio.o Modules/stringio.o  Modules/zipimport.o  Modules/faulthandler.o  Modules/_tracemalloc.o Modules/hashtable.o  Modules/symtablemodule.o  Modules/xxsubtype.o', 'MODULE_OBJS': '\\', 'MULTIARCH': 'x86_64-linux-gnu', 'MULTIARCH_CPPFLAGS': '-DMULTIARCH=\\"x86_64-linux-gnu\\"', 'MVWDELCH_IS_EXPRESSION': 1, 'NO_AS_NEEDED': '-Wl,--no-as-needed', 'OBJECT_OBJS': '\\', 'OPT': '-g -Og -Wall', 'OTHER_LIBTOOL_OPT': '', 'PACKAGE_BUGREPORT': 0, 'PACKAGE_NAME': 0, 'PACKAGE_STRING': 0, 'PACKAGE_TARNAME': 0, 'PACKAGE_URL': 0, 'PACKAGE_VERSION': 0, 'PARSER_HEADERS': '\\', 'PARSER_OBJS': '\\ Parser/myreadline.o Parser/parsetok.o Parser/tokenizer.o', 'PGEN': 'Parser/pgen', 'PGENOBJS': '\\ \\', 'PGOBJS': '\\', 'PGO_PROF_GEN_FLAG': '-fprofile-generate', 'PGO_PROF_USE_FLAG': '-fprofile-use -fprofile-correction', 'PLATDIR': '', 'POBJS': '\\', 'POSIX_SEMAPHORES_NOT_ENABLED': 0, 'PROFILE_TASK': '-m test.regrtest --pgo', 'PTHREAD_SYSTEM_SCHED_SUPPORTED': 1, 'PURIFY': '', 'PY3LIBRARY': '', 'PYLONG_BITS_IN_DIGIT': 0, 'PYTHON': 'python', 'PYTHONFRAMEWORK': '', 'PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR': 'no-framework', 'PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR': '', 'PYTHONFRAMEWORKPREFIX': '', 'PYTHONPATH': ':', 'PYTHON_FOR_BUILD': './python -E', 'PYTHON_FOR_REGEN': 'python3.6', 'PYTHON_HEADERS': '\\', 'PYTHON_OBJS': '\\', 'PY_CFLAGS': '-Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -Og -Wall', 'PY_CFLAGS_NODIST': '-std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers', 'PY_CORE_CFLAGS': '-Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -Og -Wall -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -I. -I./Include -fPIC -DPy_BUILD_CORE', 'PY_CORE_LDFLAGS': '', 'PY_CPPFLAGS': '-I. -I./Include', 'PY_FORMAT_SIZE_T': '"z"', 'PY_LDFLAGS': '', 'PY_LDFLAGS_NODIST': '', 'Py_DEBUG': 1, 'Py_ENABLE_SHARED': 1, 'Py_HASH_ALGORITHM': 0, 'QUICKTESTOPTS': '-x test_subprocess test_io test_lib2to3 \\', 'READELF': 'readelf', 'RESSRCDIR': 'Mac/Resources/framework', 'RETSIGTYPE': 'void', 'RUNSHARED': 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/usnic/Python-3.6.8', 'SCRIPTDIR': '/home/usnic/.local/lib', 'SETPGRP_HAVE_ARG': 0, 'SGI_ABI': '', 'SHELL': '/bin/sh', 'SHLIBS': '-lpthread -ldl  -lutil', 'SHLIB_SUFFIX': '.so', 'SIGNED_RIGHT_SHIFT_ZERO_FILLS': 0, 'SITEPATH': '', 'SIZEOF_DOUBLE': 8, 'SIZEOF_FLOAT': 4, 'SIZEOF_FPOS_T': 16, 'SIZEOF_INT': 4, 'SIZEOF_LONG': 8, 'SIZEOF_LONG_DOUBLE': 16, 'SIZEOF_LONG_LONG': 8, 'SIZEOF_OFF_T': 8, 'SIZEOF_PID_T': 4, 'SIZEOF_PTHREAD_T': 8, 'SIZEOF_SHORT': 2, 'SIZEOF_SIZE_T': 8, 'SIZEOF_TIME_T': 8, 'SIZEOF_UINTPTR_T': 8, 'SIZEOF_VOID_P': 8, 'SIZEOF_WCHAR_T': 4, 'SIZEOF__BOOL': 1, 'SOABI': 'cpython-36dm-x86_64-linux-gnu', 'SRCDIRS': 'Parser Objects Python Modules Programs', 'SRC_GDB_HOOKS': './Tools/gdb/libpython.py', 'STDC_HEADERS': 1, 'STRICT_SYSV_CURSES': "/* Don't use ncurses extensions */", 'STRIPFLAG': '-s', 'SUBDIRS': '', 'SUBDIRSTOO': 'Include Lib Misc', 'SYSLIBS': '-lm', 'SYS_SELECT_WITH_SYS_TIME': 1, 'TANH_PRESERVES_ZERO_SIGN': 1, 'TCLTK_INCLUDES': '', 'TCLTK_LIBS': '', 'TESTOPTS': '', 'TESTPATH': '', 'TESTPYTHON': 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/usnic/Python-3.6.8 ./python', 'TESTPYTHONOPTS': '', 'TESTRUNNER': 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/usnic/Python-3.6.8 ./python ./Tools/scripts/run_tests.py', 'TESTTIMEOUT': 1200, 'THREADOBJ': 'Python/thread.o', 'TIMEMODULE_LIB': 0, 'TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME': 1, 'TM_IN_SYS_TIME': 0, 'UNICODE_DEPS': '\\', 'UNIVERSALSDK': '', 'UPDATE_FILE': 'python3.6 ./Tools/scripts/update_file.py', 'USE_COMPUTED_GOTOS': 0, 'USE_INLINE': 1, 'VERSION': '3.6', 'WANT_SIGFPE_HANDLER': 0, 'WINDOW_HAS_FLAGS': 1, 'WITH_DOC_STRINGS': 1, 'WITH_DTRACE': 0, 'WITH_DYLD': 0, 'WITH_LIBINTL': 0, 'WITH_NEXT_FRAMEWORK': 0, 'WITH_PYMALLOC': 1, 'WITH_THREAD': 1, 'WITH_VALGRIND': 0, 'X87_DOUBLE_ROUNDING': 0, 'XMLLIBSUBDIRS': 'xml xml/dom xml/etree xml/parsers xml/sax', 'abs_builddir': '/home/usnic/Python-3.6.8', 'abs_srcdir': '/home/usnic/Python-3.6.8', 'datarootdir': '/home/usnic/.local/share', 'srcdir': '/home/usnic/.local/lib/python3.6/config-3.6dm-x86_64-linux-gnu', 'SO': '.cpython-36dm-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', 'userbase': '/home/usnic/.local'}
```

And after compile and run, another problem occurs:change of global variable in `c_py_function` can't change the behavior of `thread_fn_2` and `thread_fn_1`, because global variable can't be changed in another python script file, see `https://darkof.me/2016/08/04/python-global-var/` and I resolve this problem with the help of `https://www.cnblogs.com/dreamfine/p/8410348.html`.